# RestoreAcronyms throw errors Undefined control sequence \gls

Tags: glossaries

when using \RestoreAcronyms from glossaries-extra all \gls works as previously in glossaries but I get "Undefined control sequence \gls" errors

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\RestoreAcronyms
\newacronym{label}{acronyme}{Definition}
\newacronym[plural={acronyme pluriel},first={texte à afficher à la première occurrence},firstplural={idem, mais au pluriel}]{label2}{acronyme}{Définition}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\gls{label} foo
\gls{label} foo
\gls{label2} foo
\gls{label2} foo
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

My ultimate goal was to use \Glsfmtfull in headings as recommended but keeping the same behaviour of acronyms defined with `\newacronym{label}{acronyme}{Definition}` : in glossaries-extra without RestoreAcronyms, label (from my MWE) will never be seen "full (short)" at first display but label2 yes. I rather prefer to don't change my whole glossary file!

Comment: Looks like a bug, so make a bug report: http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/bug-report.cgi.

Comment: Thx I'm gonna check the bugtracker and post Did you get the issue too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My ultimate goal was to use \Glsfmtfull in heading

I <del>will fix</del> have now fixed this bug (v1.07), but if that's your goal, then there's no point using `\RestoreAcronyms` because all the new commands like `\Glsfmtfull` are designed to work with `glossaries-extra`'s new abbreviation mechanism and don't work with the original `glossaries` acronym mechanism.

I'm guessing that what you actually want is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\newacronym{label}{acronyme}{Definition}
\newacronym[plural={acronyme pluriel},first={texte à afficher à la
première occurrence},firstplural={idem, mais au
pluriel}]{label2}{acronyme}{Définition}

\begin{document}
\gls{label} foo
\gls{label} foo
\gls{label2} foo
\gls{label2} foo
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of result]